# Java+MySQL with JDBC connector mistake

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect Java and MySQL with JDBC connector. So, I've downloaded connector from [official cite](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), added it to classpath and added to the libraries of eclipse. 
Now i'm using the code below

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


    public class LocalhostDBConnection 
    {   
        LocalhostDBConnection()
        {
        Connection connection;
        try {
            // Название драйвера
            String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 

            Class.forName(driverName);

            // Create a connection to the database
            String serverName = "localhost";
            String mydatabase = "AvtoKovriki";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("is connect to DB" + connection);

            String query = "Select * FROM users";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(query);
            String dbtime;
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                dbtime = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(dbtime);
            } // end while

            connection.close();
        } // end try
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Could not find the database driver
        } catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Could not connect to the database
        }
        }
    }
```

But in string: ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(query); there is a mistake "Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ResultSet".
I can't understand what the problem is. Need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Statement#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) method returns a `boolean`. You are looking for the [Statement#executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) method, which returns a `ResultSet`.

Your code should be like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with MySQL - you're not getting as far as running the code, and none of your code deals with MySQL-specific types. (My point is that you may or may not have the MySQL jar file in the right place; this error isn't due to that.)

If you look at the documentation for [`Statement.execute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) you'll see that that returns `boolean`, not `ResultSet`. That's why you're getting the compile-time error.

You want [`executeQuery(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) instead - or you *could* call `execute(String)`, and if it returns true, call `getResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `executeQuery(String sql)` method

see javadocs for more details about the provided methods

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt.execute(query);
```

returns boolean not ResultSet. You can get
ResultSet by using  `stmt.executeQuery()` method for queries that won't
modify data in the database.

If you want to modify data in your Database use the `executeUpdate()` method, which will return an integer to indicate whether data has been modified or not.